# Maya 2012: Is it possible to convert a single polygon to solid object?

Tags: models, maya

Is it possible to somehow extrude a single polygon into creating a solid object (ex: converting square polygon to cube)?

Comment: So you or an employer paid $3500 for Maya, and didn't get training materials too?

Comment: I have the educational version of Maya.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the educational version comes with "getting started" videos that are presented to you when Maya first starts up, as well as under the Help menu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) select polygon
2) Edit Mesh->Extrude

Comment: You don't know how stupid I feel right now. Thanks.